# What happens to my test classes after EJB 3.1 Migration

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, ejb, ejb-3.1

I am planning to migrate an EJB2.1 Project into EJB 3.1. I have lots of Unit tests. 
What happens to my classes if i migrate my project?

- Can I **use the existing unit tests**?
- If not, does it take much time to **adapt for ejb 3.1**
- Which **advantages** does the migration bring for testing aspect.
- How can i use **Dependency Injection** in Unit Tests
- I heard about [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) for ejb3.1. would it be the right choice

Thanks in advance.